# I'm wondering why is this statement true?

Tags: functional-analysis

The space $(R^2, ||.||_1)$, where $||(x,y)||_1$ = $|x|$ +$|y|$, is a Hilbert space.
Is this statement true?

Comment: What would the inner product be?

Comment: Do you mean Banach space?

Answer (score 3):

Since $R^2$ is finite dimensional, any norm on $R^2$ is complete.

You only need to check whether $||\cdot||_1$ is a norm.

As Tyler pointed, $||\cdot||_1$ does not satisfy the parallelogram law , so this can't naturally induce an inner product.

Comment: so this statement is true?

Comment: Every finite-dimensional normed space is complete.

Comment: @Rubertos Since he's asking whether or not the space is Hilbert, just showing completeness may not be enough. He should check whether the norm satisfies the parallelogram law.

Comment: @TylerHilton You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Since the space given is finite dimensional, as Rubertos points out, the norm is complete. This is called a Banach space.

A Hilbert space is a Banach space with an additional structure called the inner product. This inner product (the notion of "angles") naturally induces a norm. To check if a norm is induced by the inner product, one can check if it satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Parallelogram_Law_(Hilbert_Space)).

Answer (score 1):

$x=(x_1,x_2)$
$ y=(y_1,y_2)$
The parallelogram law states that : $2||x||^2+2||y||^2=\frac{{||x+y||}^2+{||x-y||}^2}{4}$
$x=(1,0)$
$y=(0,1)$
$x+y=(1,1)$
$x-y=(1,-1)$
$||x||=1$
$||y||=1$
$||x+y||=2$
$||x-y||=2$
Since the parallelogram law is violated, the norm doesnot arise from an inner product.